# In MI device image name automatic change

Tags: android, camera, android-sdcard, save-image

In Mi device when i captured image from my custom camera image save perfectly to sdcard but after few minutes image name automatic change

For save image in sdcard i have used below code

```
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
                            .format(date.getTime());

file = new File(file.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator
                                       + "IMG_"
                                       + timeStamp 
                                       + ".jpg");
```

image name save as in sdcard with following format : 
IMG_1601464_142653.jpg

After few minutes image name change with IMG_1601464_142653**_152145632141214**.jpg

i don't know from where  **_152145632141214** this line is added at last of image name in MI device

Comment: because you have added "timeStamp" to the image path. Remove it and check it

Comment: @Sallu  still facing same issue